# Deploying SharePoint 2010 wsps in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have recently built a SharePoint 2013 farm and have migrated the content of a SharePoint 2010 environment mainly the ContentDB for the Intranet Web App into SharePoint 2013 via the database attach/detach method.

All the content is there and the environment is up and running. I did get the usual errors to do with missing features, web parts which are referenced in the migrated database but are not yet present/deployed in the 2013 environment.

In any case I know that SharePoint 2013 includes the 14.0 a hive for compatibility with SharePoint 2010.

Are the SharePoint 2010 WSPs normally deployed as per usual in SharePoint 2013 (using Add-SPSolution)? Do any modifications need to be made to the WSPs before deploying? or does it automatically get deployed to the correct hive (14.0 in this case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you deploy farm solutions in the same way as you did in SharePoint 2010 using the [Add-SPSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607552%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and [Install-SPSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607534%28v=office.15%29.aspx) cmdlets. SharePoint 2013 will automatically handle deploying to the appropriate hive.

So you know, you can also deploy the solutions before performing the database attach and the errors/warnings about missing features shouldn't happen thus making it easier to see the more serious errors.

Comment: Thanks, yes in hind site I should have done that first but deploying the WSPs should get rid of the errors (fingers crossed).